# Kingston SSD firmware update via USB?

Tags: ssd, firmware

I have a system with a Kingston SSD that needs to be updated to the latest firmware. The system does not have an optical drive. Is there a way to install the firware update via USB, or am I going to have to buy a CD drive just to do this update? I have Ubuntu Linux available on another machine to set things up.

Comment: Is this system with Kingston SSD running Windows? How do you know the firmware needs to be updated? Are you getting some kind of update notice? Can't you click on that and use the associated software to do the firmware updating?

Comment: What model is it?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Rufus](http://rufus.akeo.ie/) to set up a bootable USB drive with Kingston's ISO file.

Unfortunately Rufus is only available for Windows. On GNU/Linux I tried a simple `dd` and [UNetbootin](http://unetbootin.sourceforge.net/) but both failed to produced a bootable drive.

Comment: So is this a Thomas Edison answer (we know, definitively, some things that don't work)?

Comment: You can count me in. I have had bad experience with making bootable UFDs with both Windows and Linux ISO images. On Windows, I mainly use Rufus to build bootable Linux UFDs, and the Windows 7 DVD USB tool to build bootable Windows UFDs. There is also one tool called [ISO to USB](http://www.isotousb.com/). But I have had mixed result using that.

Comment: @fixer1234 If he is Edison, then I am Tesla! ;-)

Comment: @fixer1234 Rufus on Windows works for Kingston's ISO files. That's the first sentence of the answer: the thing which works.